# Is there a way to extract strong/extreme words from the text using NLP?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-processing

I am trying to extract the extreme emotion words i.e. words like great, awesome, amazing, interesting, intriguing.
Words such as good, bad, like, dislike should not be considered as extreme words.
Is there any way I can achieve this using python? I have tried some things but I am able to fetch all the words, words which just define a emotion but are not too strong are also extracted.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a lexicon or list of words that are known to be associated with extreme emotions and then search for those words in the text.
It's worth noting that the definition of "extreme emotion words" can vary depending on the context and the audience, so you may need to customize your approach based on your specific needs.